# Physics properties: Will the render be accurate without baking?

Tags: rendering, physics, baking, cache

I have a scene with lots of objects with physics on them. Dynamic paint, rigid bodies, wind, and turbulence. Now, getting all of this baked and packed in a .zip to send to a render farm is quite the hassle.

So my question is: is the baking process necessary for an accurate render, or will the physics be
calculated accurately during the actual rendering?

Comment: Sorry I can't answer that question regarding render farms, I can only tell from my personal experience in the past that sometimes physics simulations produced weird or unwanted behaviour when calculated "on the fly" while rendering the animation. But that wasn't always and I can't say anything about latest Blender versions, because nowadays I usually bake before rendering. My only advice is, if nobody can give you a safe answer, I wouldn't want to waste precious render time or money for the render farm just to find out it went all wrong.

Comment: I see, thanks for your input! I was going to use sheep it, so time or money is not an issue. Well I'll just pack the baked cache as well to be sure.

Comment: I'd say, without knowing anything about the project there's no appropriate answer. It depends on what you think is the greater fuss, baking all before rendering and pack the cache, or getting it done without baking at the risk to have to render it again.